# What are the enjoyments in heaven?

Tags: gods, swarga

Based on puranic descriptions, it seems the Devas and inhabitants of heaven party.

For example, they drink alcohol, eat meat, and have sex with Apsaras:

**Manusmriti:**

> Milk, **wine**, honey, and clarified butter are the articles which the
>   gods are fond of. (38)

**Bhagavatam:**

> Text 46: An earthly king who protects himself and all citizens by
>   removing all sins from his kingdom **will certainly enjoy with Lord
>   Indra in airplanes as brilliant as the sun.**

Also **Bhagavatam**:

> Text 23: If on earth one performs sacrifices for the satisfaction of
>   the demigods, he goes to the heavenly planets, where, **just like a
>   demigod, he enjoys all of the heavenly pleasures he has earned by his
>   performances.**
>
> Text 24: Having achieved the heavenly planets, the performer of
>   ritualistic sacrifices **travels in a glowing airplane**, which he obtains
>   as the result of his piety on earth. **Being glorified by songs sung by
>   the Gandharvas and dressed in wonderfully charming clothes, he enjoys
>   life surrounded by heavenly goddesses.**
>
> Text 25: **Accompanied by heavenly women**, the enjoyer of the fruits of
>   sacrifice goes on pleasure rides in a wonderful airplan**e, which is
>   decorated with circles of tinkling bells and which flies wherever he
>   desires**. **Being relaxed, comfortable and happy in the heavenly pleasure
>   gardens**, he does not consider that he is exhausting the fruits of his
>   piety and will soon fall down to the mortal world.
>
> Text 26: Until his pious results are used up, the performer of
>   sacrifice enjoys life in the heavenly planets. When the pious results
>   are exhausted, however, he falls down from the **pleasure gardens of
>   heaven**, being moved against his desire by the force of eternal time.

My question is, what are the other enjoyments of heaven not already listed above?